# Checking availability of a method or property in GWT Elemental2 overlays

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop

Although a property or method may be provided in an Elemental2 overlay, how can you test whether it is actually defined in the underlying JS object?

The `DomGlobal` class has a `hasOwnProperty()` method that seems to do what I want:

```
// WORKS
if (DomGlobal.hasOwnProperty("console")) {
    DomGlobal.console.log(object);
}
```

But how do I check for the existence of methods on the `console` object itself? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
// DOESN'T WORK
if (DomGlobal.console.hasOwnProperty("warn")) {
    DomGlobal.console.warn(object);
}
```

It doesn't work because `hasOwnProperty()` isn't defined in the `console` overlay.

What am I supposed to do instead? Do I need to define my own overlay or cast to an overlay that includes the method?

Is this right?

```
Js.<JsObject>cast(DomGlobal.console).hasOwnProperty("warn")
```

It seems a bit of a mouthful. Are there standard utilities for doing this more succinctly or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered this answer in an old [closed issue](https://github.com/google/elemental2/issues/5) for Elemental2 :

```
Js.asPropertyMap(object).has("key");
```